# Custom handling value when mapping by property names using Automapper

Tags: .net, automapper

I am mapping values with Automapper by property names like this:

```
.ForMember(dstPropName, a => a.MapFrom(srcPropName));
```

Is there a way for custom handling values obtained from the source? For example, I would like to trim strings.

I am making a data converter that should accept very different data types and the caller provides only column names (this is required by task). I have no idea how to intercept obtained values and do something to them.

Comment: a custom `ITypeConverter` inplementation may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found solution! IMemberValueResolver is what I need.

```
public class Source
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string TextTime { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, object, object>
{
    private readonly string _format;

    public DateTimeResolver(string format)
    {
        _format = format;
    }

    public object Resolve(object source, object destination, object sourceMember, object destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(sourceMember.ToString(), _format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) ? dt : (DateTime?) null;
    }
}

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Source src = new Source()
        {
            Text = "   message with spaces    ",
            TextTime = "04/22/1988"
        };

        DateTimeResolver dtReader = new DateTimeResolver("MM/dd/yyyy");

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            cfg.CreateMap(typeof (Source), typeof (Destination))
                // type resolver
                .ForMember("Message", opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TrimResolver, object>("Text"))
                // instance resolver
                .ForMember("CreatedOn", opt => opt.ResolveUsing(dtReader, "TextTime")));

        Destination dst =  Mapper.Map<Destination>(src);

    }
}
```